# Ajax function to fetch the selected value from the dropdown and passing that value to a function in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, drop-down-menu

i am making an application in MVC3 where in i have many dropdowns
Now on the basis of value selected in the first dropdown the second drodown is populated.
I need to write Ajax for this and i am having a tough time doing it.

I Have my first dropdown "Select Course" and now which ever course is selected With the help of that particular Course Id  the corresponding state is selected from the database.

For eg if the Course is "MCA" the states Dropdown must be populated with states such as Maharashtra,Rajasthan and soon.

I tried the Following code for Ajax but it does not work and gives me an error

```
  $("#Course").change(function () {
        var Courseid = $("#Course").val();
        var urlCourselocation = '@Url.Action("FetchstatebyCourse")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlCourselocation,
            data: { id: Courseid },
            success: function (data) {
                          $('#State').empty();
                          $('#State')
                        .append($('<option>', { value: "0" })
                        .text("-- Select State --"));
                    $.each(returndata, function (key, value) {

                    $('#State')
                        .append($('<option>', { value: value.Value })
                        .text(value.Text));
                });
               }
        });
    });
```

and in the Controller i have wrote the following function:

```
 public ActionResult FetchHobbyDetailByHobbyId(int Id)
    {
        LearnerService learnerservice = new LearnerService();
        /* Here is some Code to fetch the state id from the database*/
        ICollection<ProvincialState> state = learnerservice.FetchStateByStateid(stateid);
        ViewBag.State = state;

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new SelectList(
                            state,
                           "ProvincialStateID",
                           "ProvincialStateName"));
        return View();
    }
```

Please help me with the Code and correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: What was the error and was it on the server side or client side?

Comment: @GregB hey sorry it does not give me error but when i select Course it doesnot populate anything inside State dropdown apart from this:"--Select State---"

Comment: If you have firebug installed I would look at the post response and see what kind of data you get back (probably empty). Also I think you might want to consider returning Json(state) only and see what it gives you. Also, step through the server side code and make sure it's returning something

Comment: @GregB hey this may shock u but while debugging i can see what it returns and it is exactly what i wantd to fetch but the returned value does not show up in the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I think I saw the issue...
shouldn't :

```
 $.each(returndata, function (key, value) {
```

be

```
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
```